# not able to understand MuiSvgIcon

Tags: css, svg

Hi Everyone I am not able to under stand below css. can somebody let me know how it will work

```
.sidebar__headerRight > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    margin-top: 2vw;
    font-size: 24px !important;
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand ? `>` in the selector, `vw` unit, `!important` ?

Comment: MuiSvgIcon-root.

Comment: `.sidebar__headerRight > .MuiSvgIcon-root` will target every elements with the class `MuiSvgIcon-root` wich are the direct child of an element with the class `sidebar__headerRight`

Comment: @CedricCholley..okay thanks